# how to read records from ESE database using cpp

Tags: c++, esent, extensible-storage-engine

I have open the ESE database successfully by using **JetOpenDatabase** API. 
To read the records I have open the "MSysObjects" table and set the current index to the "RootObjects".

Here's my code (without error-handling):

```
err = ::JetOpenTable(sessionID,dbID,"MSysObjects",NULL,0,0,&tableId);
err = ::JetSetCurrentIndex( sessionID, tableId, "RootObjects" );
err = ::JetMove( sessionID, tableId, JET_MoveFirst, 0 );
```

to read the records I have tried the **JetRetrieveColumns** function to retrieves multiple column values from the current record. I have also tried **JetRetrievedColumn** function but I didn't get the actual result.

Is any one know that how to read the records from existing and unmounted ESE database files by using cpp?

Answer (score 1):

The esent engine gives you a hint of what went wrong by the error code. Look it up here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269297(v=exchg.10).aspx

In general you have to prepare the JET_RETRIEVECOLUMN before you do actually try to read the data via **JetRetrieveColumn(s)**, by selecting which columns you want to retrieve, preparing buffer/pointers, etc. Of course there's more to it, but you should be a little bit more specific with your question.

Comment: Hi Fotis Mouratidis, can you please give me an example to retrieve the data from existing  ESE database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Fotis gives good advice. The specific error codes are very valuable. Since you're looking for example code, some of the more comprehensive example code is written in C#.

Take a look at the EsentInteropTests at https://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. Search for RetrieveColumn, and it will give you a good idea on which orders to call in which order. Sure, it's not the right language, but you can easily translate.

I presume you're using MSysObjects as an example because every database has that table. It's for internal use, and can be fairly cryptic to decipher.

-martin

Comment: I can now read the columns of type integer but I am still  can not read the columns having string values. I am getting the error JET_errColumnNotFound. I am sure that the columnid I am giving is correct. Please let me know how to read the string values from the table. Here is the code

Comment: `JET_COLUMNID columnid = 12;
       
           wchar_t buffer[ 2048 ] = { 0 };
           err = ::JetRetrieveColumn( sessionID,
           tableId,
            columnid,
            &buffer,
            sizeof( buffer ),
           NULL,
            0,
           NULL);`

Comment: If you get that error message you should trust it and look up the columnId again. Before calling JetRetrieveColumn, you should call JetGetColumnInfo to get the correct ColumnId.

Comment: `JetRetrieveColumn` takes a void* as the buffer, so the compiler won't help you very much for type-checking. You should either pass in `buffer` or `&buffer[0]` as the parameter. You'll probably clobber your stack with the code you have.